# Fill nth columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), 
           B=c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
           C=c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.5))

> df
  A B   C 
1 a 1 0.1 
2 b 1 0.2 
3 c 1 0.4 
4 d 2 0.1 
5 e 2 0.5 
6 f 2 0.7 
7 g 3 0.1 
8 h 3 0.2 
9 i 3 0.5
```

I would like to add 1000 further columns and fill this columns with the values generated by :

```
transform(df, D=ave(C, B, FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=TRUE)))
```

I've tried with a `for` loop but it does not work:

```
for (i in 4:1000){
  df[, 4:1000] <- NA
  df[,i] = transform(df, D=ave(C, B, FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=TRUE)))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency reasons, I suggest running `sample` only once for each group. This can be achieved with this:

```
sample2 <- function(x, size)
{
    if(length(x)==1) rep(x, size) else sample(x, size, replace=TRUE)
}


new_df <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$B,
            function(d) cbind(d, matrix(sample2(d$C, length(d$C)*1000), 
                                        ncol=1000))))
```

Notes:

1. I've created `sample2` in case there is a group with only one `C` value. Check `?sample` to see what I mean.
2. The names of the columns will be numbers, from 1 to 1000. This can be changed as in the answer by @agstudy.
3. The row names are also changed. "Fixing" them is similar, just use `row.names` instead of `col.names`.

Comment: Thanks @Ferdinand.kraft, I still don't understand completely your code, just to make sure, `d$C` values picked with sample2 correspond to those with the same `df$B` values right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation,@Ferdinand.kraft. Indeed, there is some groups with only one value, so your sample2 function solves the problem. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `replicate` for example:

```
cbind(df,replicate(1000,ave(df$C, df$B, 
           FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=TRUE))))
```

To add 4 columns for example:

```
 cbind(df,replicate(4,ave(df$C, df$B, 
     FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=TRUE))))

  A B   C   1   2   3   4
1 a 1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.2
2 b 1 0.2 0.4 0.2 0.4 0.4
3 c 1 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
4 d 2 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5 0.1
5 e 2 0.5 0.7 0.1 0.5 0.1
6 f 2 0.7 0.1 0.7 0.7 0.7
7 g 3 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.2 0.2
8 h 3 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.1
9 i 3 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.5
```

Maybe you need to rename columns by something like :

```
gsub('([0-9]+)','D\\1',colnames(res))
1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4"
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy, your approach also works perfectly. I've marked the second answer as the right one for avoiding the undesired behaviour of `sample` when only there is a group with only one value. But, thanks a lot!!!!!!!